# Нужна ли запятая перед "как удав"?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

За это время мальчик стал спокойный как удав.

Comment: Чаще используются сочетания СТАЛ спокойным, спокоен.Например: Я вообще спокоен как удав.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, запятая не нужна: это фразеологизм.

> **Спокоен как удав** *кто* — о спокойном, уравновешенном или равнодушном человеке.

http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_13109

Answer (score 1):

Запятая, скорее всего, нужна. Сравните с вашим примером: **Он спокоен как удав**. Вот здесь не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не ставится: "как удав" является фразеологическим оборотом. 
                                            Запятая перед "как не ставится:
1) Оборот имеет значение образа действия (без добавочных значений):  Люди стояли как камни ( Мы же не скажем: стояли подобно камням.  Камни лежат, а не стоят);
2) Основное значение оборота - отождествление, приравнивание, например:  Любое народное произведение... обязательно должно рассматриваться как ценность культуры всего человечества (Д.Лихачев);
3) Оборот - устойчивое выражение (как и у вас в примере);
4)  Перед оборотом стоит частица "не" или  слова "точь-в-точь", "совсем": Он точь-в-точь как зверь.  Он  совсем как идиот;
5) Оборот образует именую часть составного сказуемого.